# Upgrade from slick-extensions-2.1.0 to Slick-3.2.0

Tags: scala, slick, scala-2.12

I was upgrading my project from scala 2.11 to scala 2.12.

For DB Interaction slick-extentions was used, but I found out that slick-extension has been merged with Slick itself since Slick-3.2.0.

While I was going through the docs I found about `JdbcProfiles` and discontinuation of Drivers etc.

Now, I have a lot of code where `withSession` method from  `scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend` has been used - like -

```
db.withSession { implicit session =>
      rmobVersionControl.foreach(e =>
        elements += new RMOBVersionControlElement(e._1, e._2, e._3))
}
```

In the docs I see that `withSession()` method is Deprecated (Since version 3.0).

But I was wondering if there's a way to keep this code in slick 3.2.0 because changing all this code and using Action-Based Api would be a lot of pain.